# Error locking state: Error acquiring the state lock: state blob is already locked

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting this error when I try to do any operation:

`Error locking state: Error acquiring the state lock: state blob is already locked`

How can I list the people currently have a lock and how long the lock has been acquired for?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The easiest fix for this issue is to:

(1) navigate to the storage account,

(2) then to the  container in the Azure portal that holds the state file.

(3) The blob will show as ‘***Leased***’ under the leased state column.

(4) Select the state file, and hit the ‘***break lease***’ button.

*FYI: You need PIM (Privileged Identity Management (PIM)) to do this.

Quote from [Fixing Terraform ‘Error acquiring state lock’ in Azure](https://jackwesleyroper.medium.com/fixing-terraform-error-acquiring-state-lock-in-azure-ec1a5d9d5cbd#:%7E:text=On%20the%20next%20run%2C%20you,state%20blob%20is%20already%20locked%27.&text=The%20easiest%20fix%20for%20this,that%20holds%20the%20state%20file.&text=Select%20the%20state%20file%2C%20and,the%20%27break%20lease%27%20button.)

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Depends on the mechanism used for state locking.

You can see this in the config (for example in terraform.tf, when used as filename..)

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.13.4"
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "my.state.bucket.for.terraform"
    key            = "infra/my.tfstate"
    region         = "eu-central-1"
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "my.locking.table.in.dynamo"
  }
}
```

If dynamobdb (on aws) is used, simply check the table. Same for PostgreSQL or whatever.

To fix it, you can release the state from your client:

```
terraform force-unlock <ID_OF_LOCK_SHOWN_IN_ERROR>
```

Comment: This worked on azure using a storage account.

Answer (score 4):

if use old terraform version:
terraform cannot auto unlock when you force to break. so you need to unlock mannually.
portal->storage account->your account->containers->your container->your xxx.tfstate file-> click the break lease button

if button is not available, it means your state is unlocked

Answer (score 1):

Maybe doesn't exactly answer your question description but here is a way this unintentional locking situation could be avoided.

I faced this issue when trying to run a `Terraform Init` and `Terraform Plan` from two different instances of AzureCLI task. Move all the terraform commands to a single instance of the task and that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple: got to the storage account -> container and then select the state file -> break lease option.